# VBS to find file with date and to change that date to the previous day

Tags: date, vbscript

New here and VERY new to VBS so please easy.

I have a set of files that are sent via `FTP` to a folder on a server, the naming structure of these files are:

```
waw_29_2013-09-09_act_v001.csv
waw_29_2013-09-09_amf_v001.csv
waw_29_2013-09-09_inc_v001.csv
waw_29_2013-09-09_nbs_v001.csv
waw_29_2013-09-09_trn_v001.csv
waw_29_2013-09-09_val_v001.csv
waw_29_2013-09-09_wth_v001.csv
```

What I am trying to achieve is for a script to scan the folder that contains these files, and change the name to the previous day but keep the structure of the naming convention.

I have tried this on a file in my `c:\ drive` (I am very new so please excuse my lack of understanding)

```
**Dim file1, file2

file1 = "C:\fake_%date%.txt"

file2 = "C:\waw_" & year(date) & -month(date) & -Day(Date) & "_act_v001.csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FileExists(file1) = true then
    If fso.FileExists(file2) = true then
        fso.DeleteFile(file2)
    End if
    fso.MoveFile file1, file2
'else
'    msgbox "File does not exist"
End If 

Set FSO = Nothing**
```

The is on a file (as a test) called `c:\fake_2013-09-09.txt` and it is trying to scan the c:\ drive for that file (regardless of the date) and then rename this file to `"waw_29_2013-09-09_act_v001.csv"`
.

I also need the same script to run separately but to change the date back **3** days for weekends too.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Take care

Mike

Hello again

I have gotten a little further:

I have now amended the script to look as follows:

```
Dim file1, file2

file1 = "C:\winter\waw_29_2013-09-10_act_v001.csv"
file2 = "C:\winter\waw_29_" & -Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right

("0" & -Day(Date),2) & "_act_v001.csv" 

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FileExists(file1) = true then
    If fso.FileExists(file2) = true then
        fso.DeleteFile(file2)
    End if
    fso.MoveFile file1, file2
'else
```

'    msgbox "File does not exist"
   End If

```
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Now I have 2 questions about the script as I think it is 90% there:

- The line in File1, how can I get this to search for the file but to only search on the and _act field?
- Under File2, I can get the system to now produce a date for the file (the wrong date but I am getting there) but the format is 20130909 and not 2013-09-09 as I need. How do I add in the "-" between dates as it fails if I leave the "& Right("0")" in to create the leading "0" but if I take that out, it will put the "-" in but no leading )!!!
- My last question is I have found the DateAdd command that allows me to search the file and then change the date to the previous date.....my problem is I don't know where to put that in the code.

Guys if you can help, I would be really grateful.

Mike

WOW thank you so much, really helped a lot and solved the second part of my issue.
Do you know how to search a folder for a set parameter so I can search a folder named "waw_29_2013-09-09_act_v001.csv" but to exclude the date section from the search?

Again thank you so much, I learnt a lot from that part of the script

Mike

Answer (score 0):

For building a date string of the form `YYYY-MM-DD` you need to concatenate the date portions and the interleaving hyphens:

```
d = Date
Year(d) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(d), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(d), 2)
```

For building a date string of 3 days ago you do the same, but subtract 3 days from the current date first:

```
d = Date - 3
Year(d) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(d), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(d), 2)
```